# Heroku API connection to on-premise SQL server

Tags: heroku

Our developer wants to upload an API to Heroku but it needed him to be able to connect back to our database on prem. Any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: It's possible, but probably not a very good idea. You'll have to open up a route from the Internet to your internal network. This is (or at least can be) fairly basic networking, but it's off-topic here. You can read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.